# Google Analytics : Capturing outbound link clicks without passing the url of link

Tags: google-analytics

I wish to implement event tracking on external outbound link clicks with google analytics on my site.

The documentation states : "Outbound link and form tracking can be accomplished by sending events and specifying the destination URL in one of the event fields"

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

The example in the documentation passes the url in the label field when calling 'ga', however I wish to set this field with a value of my own. Can the url be passed in another field? I have left out the url completely and the event registers successfully on google analytics. However I am reluctant to use this function out of spec.

So in summary, can one use a custom label when registering an outbound link click event and if so what is the correct way to do so?

Documentation code:

```
function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href,
    transport: 'beacon'
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can name it anything you want (don't set it(not recommended), static values, variables, etc). It isn't out of spec. The documentation is just showing you some ways it can be implemented.

Example:

```
function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
       eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
       eventAction: 'click',
       eventLabel: 'MyGoTapaidh',
       transport: 'beacon'
    });
}
```

You should consider keeping either the URL or the text that people clicked on as it provides valuable information on what was clicked on the page.